# MVC5 Dropdownlist static data troubles on submitting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In view file, I am adding data to dropdownlist hard coded.

**View: Create.cshtml**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Only Male", Value = "" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Only Female", Value = "" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Combined", Value = "" }
             }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This is what I have in scaffolded controller:

**Controller: EventsController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.HallID = new SelectList(db.Halls, "HallID", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EventsID,HallID,Name,Date_Of_Occurence,time,description,seats,Event_for_Gender,Event_Coordinator,Event_Coord_phone,Event_Coord_email,Event_for_Whom")] Events events)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Events.Add(events);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.HallID = new SelectList(db.Halls, "HallID", "Name",  events.HallID);
        return View(events);
    }
```

This is the base model.
    **Model : Events.cs:**

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    [Display(Name = "Invite")]
    public string Event_for_Gender { get; set; }
```

I am new to MVC.I know this is not the correct form of coding.

**Problem:**

```
- I have the data added to dropdown list but Whenever I submit the page, the validation message shows "This field is required".  
- I have tried the ViewData from controller, which is also resulting the same.
```

Please suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: your dropdown list must have the same name that the field you want it to be bind.

2:your values always are empty

try this :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Event_for_Gender", new List<SelectListItem>

             {
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Only Male", Value = "Only Male" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Only Female", Value = "Only Female" },
                new SelectListItem{ Text="Combined", Value = "Combined" }
             }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```